# How does the init function work in plugins?

Tags: jquery

Sorry if this is a base question but I seem to have a misconception on how plugins in JQuery work and Google ain't helping much.

Imagine I have:

```
methods = {
    init : function(opts){

        options = $.extend(options, opts);

        return this.each(function(){
            data = $(this).data('prodigal');

            if(!data){

                if(options.isActive === false){
                    $(options.tpl.overlay).css({ 'opacity': options.overlay.opacity }).appendTo('body');
                    options.isActive = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Now `options.isActive` is a boolean of `true` or `false` to say whether or not the `options.tpl.overlay` option should be added to the `body` of the document. It ensures my `options.tpl.overlay` appends only once to the document and it works, but I am unsure how it works.

When I call:

```
$('.view_title_images').prodigal();
$('.glglg').prodigal();
```

It still only adds once. I was always led to believe that the plugin is formed and the init function called for every "call" you make, i.e. `$('.view_title_images,.glglg').prodigal();` would form and call the `init` function once.

So how exactly does the `init` function run in a JQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing this behaviour because the plugin is actually instantiated the first time it is run as a static object within the jQuery plugin framework.

So every successive call to the `init` function will call this global object. Since the `options` object is a reference to that object in the static object changing the boolean each time is actually saved for future calls to the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is what is happening here but be aware that `$(this)` is [not the same object](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) whether being inside or outside a callback function.

Comment: Sorry yea I stand by my last comment I am not using `this` I am uisng `$(this)`

Comment: I still don't understand, in that article he says in his code snippets `    // now we are inside of a jQuery function, the DOM element is the context
    // so 'this' has changed to become a DOM element.
` which means that the way I can expect it to be what I ask for on my plugin

Comment: " which means that the way I can expect it to be what I ask for on my plugin" What I mean't was: I can expect `$(this)` to be what I expect it to be in my plugins `init` function